# Calculating sum in php

Tags: php

I'm a beginner in PHP and I was given the assignment to print out the harmonic series. Through my work, you can see that I have printed the correct algorithim for the harmonic series, but I can't seem to find a way to add them all up.

```
$total = 0;

if ($f1 = "proof") {
    $i = $_GET["i"];

    for($j= 1;$j<=$i;$j++) {
        $total = $total +( 1/$j);
    }
echo $total;
```

Thanks for your time

---

Thanks! It worked! Here is what I used

```
$i = 3;
$total = 0;

for($j= 1; $j<=$i ;$j++){

    $total += $j/($j + 1);
}
echo $total;
```

Comment: That code looks like it should work to me. What happens when you run it?

Comment: you can try `if ($f1 === "proof")`

Comment: Regarding your edit, how does that work? It's adding `1/2 + 2/3 + 3/4`.

Comment: It worked with the edit. I can't find the up arrow for the person that helped me

Comment: @irrelephant This is what my professor had as the example. The sum of 1/2 + 2/3 + 3/4 etc. is the answer I needed.

Comment: Strange; that's not the harmonic series, then. `$total = $total + ($j/($j + 1));` should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version:

```
<?php

    $total = 0;
    foreach(range(1, 3) as $v)
        $total += $v/($v+1);
    echo $total;

?>
```

Output:

```
1.9166666666667
```

BTW: In your if statement you make a assignment! You don't compare! you would have to use `==` OR `===`

Comment: Surely `$total = $total + ____` is fine, though?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the bug is here:

```
if ($f1 = "proof")
```

The = assigns the value of "proof" to the variable $f1 and doesn't evaluate equality like you want. What you really want is

```
if ($f1 === "proof")
```

which does an equality check. == works as well, it just doesn't check that types are the same (so 0=="0" evaluates to true, while 0==="0" would not)